# Doubts about joint distribution function notation

Tags: probability

I am given a table that describes the joint probability function of two discrete random variables.

$$
\begin{matrix}
\hline
x/y & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
0 & 1/30 & 2/30 & 3/30 \\
1 & 4/30 & 0 & 6/30 \\
2 & 5/30 & 4/30 & 5/30 \\
\hline
\end{matrix}
$$

Finding the probabilities is usually a matter of referencing the table and getting the value: $P(X=1,Y=0)=4/30$, or adding the items that match the expression (say, the inequality), such as $P(X>0,Y\leq 1)=4/30+0+5/30+4/30=13/30$.

However now I'm seeing notations I don't fully understand. For the same table, I'm required to find: $P(X=0\mid Y=2)$, $P(XY=0)$, $P(XY\geq 2)$ and $P(X+Y \text{ is odd})$. How should I proceed with these notations, what do they mean? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one simply means $P(X=0)$ given $Y=2$ and so it is equivalent to $\dfrac{P(X=0\bigcap Y=2)}{P(Y=2)}$. The second one simply requires you to consider the cases where $XY=0$ and add up the corresponding probabilities in the table. The third one is similar, though this time it involves an inequality. And finally, just find the values of $X$ and $Y$ that make $X+Y$ odd and add the corresponding probabilities in the table for the last one.

Comment: Hi thanks. Let me see if I follow. $P(Y=2)$ would mean $P(X=0,Y=2)+P(X=1,Y=2)+P(X=2,Y=2)$, right? How does the $\cap$ translate in this case? Does it mean "where $X=0$ and $Y=2$, which should be $3/30$, is that correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct for both.

Comment: thank you, got the result 3/14 out of the suggestions you made, which happened to be the correct answer according to the book. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$P(X=0\mid Y=2)$ means the probability that $X=0$ *given* that $Y=2$. Of the $3+6+5=14$ outcomes where $Y=2$, we observe $X=0$ in exactly $3$ of them, so $P(X=\mid Y=2)=3/14)$. In general, the conditional probality is given by $P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$, where $A$ and $B$ are events (remember an event means a set of outcomes).

$P(XY=0)$ is the probability of the event "$XY=0$." So, look at all outcomes where $XY=0$ (i.e. where at least one of $X$ or $Y$ is $0$) and add up the corresponding probabilities. Similarly, $P(X+Y\textrm{ is odd})$ is the probability that the sum $X+Y$ is odd, so look at all possible pairs of outcomes where $X+Y$ is odd (i.e. where $X$ and $Y$ differ in parity) and add up the corresponding probabilities.